# NVIDIA Prime auto switch on multiple monitors

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xps

I am new to Ubuntu (used to other distros). I have a XPS15 with a GeForce GTX 1650.

I want to use my laptop with another 4k monitor (in sum an external 4k monitor, and the laptop monitor is also 4k). I think I have solved the resolution issue by using xrandr.

Although when I use both monitors with the Nvidia drive in "on demand" mode it gets super slow. I would like to know if there is a way to setup ubuntu 20.04 (running Gnome) so that the driver is setup into "performance" mode when using an external monitor, and into "on demand" when only  using the laptop monitor?

Thank you ;)

Comment: You can select the desired profile at Nvidia X Server Settings.